# How does the header of a collection view automatically go up when an item below is focused?

Tags: header, uicollectionview, tvos

[image]

As you can see both the title label and the header view will move away to make room for the focused ImageView. When the header view has a longer label then this also occurs on the second item. How where they able to accomplish this?